# How to write custom method ++= for my custom mutable.HashMap

Tags: scala, java-8

I hvae written map like below, my implementation of mutable.HashMap.

```
class SampleMap() extends mutable.HashMap[String, (Any, BigInt)]
```

And overriden += method of map and rest of the methods are used from super class not overriden. Below works perfectly.

```
override def +=(kv: (String, (Any, BigInt))): this.type = {/*compiled code*/}
```

Now I want to write my custom implementation of ++= method which is inherited from growable class by Map. when I write overriden method ++=, Compiler complains nothing to override.

```
override def ++=(currentMap: MergeMap): this.type  = {
```

How to write custom implementation of this method for my custom Map.

Comment: Note the type signature: `def ++=(xs: TraversableOnce[A]): this.type`. Without a specified type parameter, the compiler is unable to tie `MergeMap` with `TraversableOnce[A]`. Thus the two are unrelated and no override is involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to override `scala.collection.generic.Growable.++=` method:

```
class SampleMap() extends mutable.HashMap[String, (Any, BigInt)] {
  override def ++=(xs: TraversableOnce[(String, (Any, BigInt))]): this.type = {
    this
  }
}
```

then works well:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    new SampleMap() ++= mutable.HashMap.empty[String, (Any, BigInt)]
  }
```